# node js heroku interact with postgresql

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, heroku, psql

I am trying to add a PostgreSQL database to my existing nodejs project on heroku. I am having trouble accessing the local version of the database at all, and also having trouble writing to the heroku database.
Here is part of the code that I have tried:

```
const { Client } = require('pg');

const client = new Client({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: true,
});

client.connect();

// client
let qu = 'SELECT table_schema,table_name FROM information_schema.tables;';
//qu = 'CREATE TABLE test (name varchar(40));';
//qu = 'SELECT * FROM test;';
// qu = 'INSERT INTO test name VALUES("testasdf");';
// qu = 'CREATE DATABASE X

client.query(qu, (err, res) => {
  //console.log("trying");
  if (err) throw err;
  for (let row of res.rows) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
  }
  client.end();
});
```

I have tried following the instructions here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql

but I can't access the local database or do anything to the remote one.

Here is the local error message:

(node:8402) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: error: password authentication failed for user "..."
    at Connection.parseE (.../theland/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:553:11)
    at Connection.parseMessage (.../theland/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:378:19)
    at TLSSocket. (.../theland/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:119:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:263:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:250:11)
    at TLSSocket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:208:10)
    at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:597:20)
(node:8402) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8402) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I don't know how to create a table on the remote one.

I am running on Linux with 
node-v = 8.11.2
npm-v = 6.1.0
pg: ^7.4.3

I am using psql too, no GUI.

Thanks for the help.

EDIT---
Where should I add the authentication? Do I need to take the script off of github if I add the authentication and don't want people to be able to be admins for my database?

Answer (score 0):

1. > password authentication failed for user "..."

Obviously you are not using the right password for the user. The positive news is that there is a server responding your request.

2. > Unhandled promise rejection

There is an error, probably thrown here:

```
if (err) throw err;
```

You seem not to catch it somewhere, you only throw it. Try to put it into some try-catch-block, e.g. like

```js
function queryDatabase() {
  try {
    const client = new Client({
      connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
      ssl: true,
    });

    client.connect();

    // client
    let qu = 'SELECT table_schema,table_name FROM information_schema.tables;';
    //qu = 'CREATE TABLE test (name varchar(40));';
    //qu = 'SELECT * FROM test;';
    // qu = 'INSERT INTO test name VALUES("testasdf");';
    // qu = 'CREATE DATABASE X

    client.query(qu, (err, res) => {
      //console.log("trying");
      if (err) throw err;
      for (let row of res.rows) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
      }
      client.end();
    });
  } catch (error) {
    // if you need further help, remember to provide this error here.
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```